# NSDictionary load information of 18 key-value pairs always read as nil instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

```
    - (instancetype)initWithDestinationIndex:(NSUInteger)levelsIndex {
          NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                          pathForResource:@"Levels" ofType:@"plist"];
          NSDictionary *levels = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
          NSArray *levelsArray = levels[@"LevelsData"];
          _data = levelsArray[levelsIndex];
          [_verticalB setToInitialStateVertical];
          return self;
    }
```

I have a `plist` that is supposed to load information of 18 key-value pairs.  The `_data` of type `NSDictionary` instance variable (when I run the program and put a breakpoint at that line `_data = levelsArray[levelsIndex];`) is almost always null, except on one occasion where it is actually had the 18 key-value pairs loaded.  Any thoughts as to why it pretty much always is null?

I pass in 0 for my `levelsIndex`, and the 'LevelsData' is the `NSArray` that holds the 18 key-value pair dictionaries.

Comment: what is the _data variable NSArray or NSDictionary

Comment: Please post your plist file. And also, at your breakpoint what is the value of the levels variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your _data is `NSMutableDictionary` use the below code,

```
NSMutableDictionary *_data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_data setObject:[levelsArray objectAtIndex: levelsIndex] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", levelsIndex]];
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<[levelsArray count]; i++){
    [_data setObject:[levelsArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: I'm able to read the information now.  Turn out it was because my initialization for the plist was only in my Model class (which is a subclass of another Model, which is subclassed from NSObject).  It seemed to fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that, you are running app in a "release" scheme. Have you double check? As long as you're getting the result.

To check,

> Click on Project Name next to [Run] button. > Edit Scheme > Run > Build Configuration > Debug/Release